# Merge two arrays, one array each 5 key

Tags: php

I'm trying to merge 2 arrays but I would like to add my first array each 5 key.

```
$main_list = array(data-main-1, data-main-2, data-main-3, data-main-4, data-main-5, data-main-6, data-main-7, data-main-8, data-main-9, data-main-10); 
$programme_list = array(data-programme-1, data-programme-2, data-programme-3);

$complete_list = array(data-programme-1, data-main-1, data-main-2, data-main-3, data-main-4, data-programme-2, data-main-5, data-main-6, data-main-7, data-main-8, programme-2, data-main-9, data-main-10)
```

### **Example :**

- **data-programme-1**
- data-main-1
- data-main-2
- data-main-3
- data-main-4
- **data-programme-2**
- data-main-5
- data-main-6
- data-main-7
- data-main-8
- **data-programme-3**
  .....

### I wrote this but with odd/even system (all works fine but not the solution for me) :

```
$main_list = get_field('home_list_main');
$programme_list = get_field('home_list_programme');

$complete_list = array();

foreach($main_list as $key => $value) {
    $complete_list[] = $value;

    if (isset($programme_list[$key])) {
        $complete_list[] = $programme_list[$key];
    }
}

echo $complete_list;
```

**How can I do please ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first split the main list into 5's (using `array_chunk()` in this example), you can then add the programme followed by the corresponding chunk...

```
$complete_list = [];
$mainChunk = array_chunk($main_list, 5);
foreach ( $programme_list as $key => $programme )   {
    $complete_list[] = $programme;
    $complete_list = array_merge($complete_list, $mainChunk[$key] ?? []);
}
```

Using `$mainChunk[$key] ?? []` in case their isn't data for this item and just default it to an empty array.

Comment: I searched for hours on the internet for a solution, without success. I didn't know array_chunk ()! Your solution works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help ! To change the position of the inputs, simply modify the parameters of array_chunk () ?